# Sending JSON request in SoapUI tool using Groovy Script

Tags: json, grails, soap, groovy

I am sending JSON files as request and getting responses in soap UI tool using Groovy script for Rest Project.

But I found error in step 2, as it is not retrieving the content of JSON file. Below is my code.

### Steps:

1. Retrieving data from json file
2. content from json file should place in body (parameters), send request and get response
3. the response should pass it to json file and validate the response

### Step 1 (Script)

```
File file1 = new File("C:\\GroovyTest\\requests\\aaa.json")     
List textLine = file1.readLines()          
log.info textLine     
context.put('textLine', textLine)      
log.info textLine
```

### Step 2 (Script)

```
${=new File("C:\\GroovyTest\\requests\\"+(context.get('filelist')).last()).text)
```

### Step3 (Script)

```
def fileList = context.get('fileList')    
if (fileList != null)    
{    
 def fileName = fileList.pop()    

def newname = fileName[0..-5]    

def response = context.expand( '${Step2#Response}' )    
def f = new File("C:\\GroovyTest\\responses\\${fileName}_Response.xml")    
f.write(response, "UTF-8")     

if(fileList.size() >0)     
{
 testRunner.gotoStepByName("Step2")     
}
}
```

Comment: what error do you see? Do you need to send the whole content of the file from json file?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: In step2,Error is showing as  "{"error": "Error parsing jsondocument Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: $. Path '', line 0, position 0."}"                                                                                                                               can you please send me the full code which works for json file sending request and getting response

Comment: because of your step2 is not well formatted, the brackets are not closing and `=` what are doing there?

Comment: even i gave this script in step 2,                                                           
${=new File("C:\\GroovyTest\\requests\\"+(context.get('filelist')).last()).text)      I got this error:  {"error": "Error parsing jsondocument Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: $. Path '', line 0, position 0."}                                                  
Please any one solve my problem or send me new code